# Firing attack and take_damage events on entity attacking?

Tags: python, entity-system, rpg

I have an `Entity` class with health, armor, and damage.
I want my entities to raise some kind of `take_damage` and `attack` events whenever they attack or take damage. Here's my current implementation:

```
class Entity:


   """Base class for all entities."""

    def __init__(self, name, health, armor=0, damage=0):
        """Initializes a new entity."""
        self.name = name
        self.base_health = health
        self.base_armor = armor
        self.base_damage = damage
        self.events = event_dict('take_damage', 'die', 'attack', 'kill')

    def take_damage(self, damage, attacker=None):
        """Takes damage from a source."""
        final_damage = damage * (self.armor / (100 + self.armor))
        self.base_health -= final_damage
        self.events['take_damage'].fire(
            attacker=attacker,
            victim=self,
            damage=final_damage,
            raw_damage=damage
        )
        if self.base_health <= 0:
            self.events['die'].fire(
                attacker=attacker,
                victim=self
            )
        return final_damage

    def attack(self, victim):
        """Attacks a victim."""
        final_damage = victim.take_damage(self.damage)
        self.events['attack'].fire(
            attacker=self,
            victim=victim,
            damage=final_damage,
            raw_damage=self.damage
        )
        if not victim.alive:
            self.events['kill'].fire(
                attacker=self,
                victim=victim
            )

    @property
    def health(self):
        """Getter for entity's health."""
        return self.base_health

    @property
    def armor(self):
        """Getter for entity's armor."""
        return self.base_armor

    @property
    def alive(self):
        """Getter for entity's alive state."""
        return self.base_health <= 0

    @property
    def damage(self):
        """Getter for entity's damage."""
        return self.base_damage
```

First of all, I'm really new to game developing, so any improvements would be nice.
The problem I'm having is that I'm "forced" to return a value from the `take_damage()` method, in order to include the actual damage in `attack()`'s event arguments. Would there be any fix for this?

Comment: When I play pen and paper (and d20) RPGs , I know my to-hit _roll_ and damage _roll_, I don't know the actual final damage, only the DM and the victims know. Why would the 'attack' know the final damage in your situation? Why are the events needed?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt The events are there for items and spells; if an item wants to interfere with the attack (say, deal `10%` extra damage),  it simply listens to the entity's attack event with a function like this: http://pastebin.com/ZDaAA1j1

Comment: Hmm, ok, I think I see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

```
def compute_final_damage(self, raw_damage):
    """Apply armor to the damage"""
    return raw_damage * (self.armor / (100 + self.armor))

def take_damage(self, damage, attacker=None):
    """Takes damage from a source."""
    final_damage = self.compute_final_damage(damage)
    self.base_health -= final_damage
    self.events['take_damage'].fire(
        attacker=attacker,
        victim=self,
        damage=final_damage,
        raw_damage=damage
    )
    if self.base_health <= 0:
        self.events['die'].fire(
            attacker=attacker,
            victim=self
        )

def attack(self, victim):
    """Attacks a victim."""
    final_damage = victim.compute_final_damage(self.damage)
    victim.take_damage(self.damage)
    self.events['attack'].fire(
        attacker=self,
        victim=victim,
        damage=final_damage,
        raw_damage=self.damage
    )
    if not victim.alive:
        self.events['kill'].fire(
            attacker=self,
            victim=victim
        )
```

You delegate the computation of the `final_damage` to a third method, which will be called by both `take_damage` and `attack` methods. It's unfortunate you have to call the same method twice, I don't really see any other options with your current architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> The events are there for items and spells; if an item wants to interfere with the attack (say, deal 10% extra damage), it simply listens to the entity's attack event with a function [...]

Now that it's clear what you use the event for, here's a different suggestion architecture-wise:

**Items listen for the `take_damage` event. If the item's owner is the damage dealer, enqueue the special effect via your function.**

That helps keeping events distinct: the `take_damage` event is pretty similar to the `attack` event *in its use.* It is meant to signify something else, though.

- Use `take_damage` to notify "the world" about all the details of being damaged.
- Use `attack` to notify "the world" that X attacks Y, maybe with details about the weapon, but without final damage info. Raw damage is okay if it cannot be obtained easily.

Use both events for example to log what is happening:

> - *X* attacks *Y* with Broadsword! (`attack` event)
> - *Y* takes 123 damage!  (`take_damage` event)
> - *Y* is badly hurt.  (imaginary `status_change` event, based on taking damage so that leftover HP is <10%)

Subscribe to the attack event in a fighting coordinator object. Let it react to an attack by letting the receiver taking the actual damage.

This decouples the damage dealer from the victim further. You could also let the coordinator decide if an attack is an actual hit, or if the ground is muddy and the dealer should miss, or whatever circumstances *not themselves being part of the damage dealer* affect an attack.